# Skip displaying page if back button is pressed

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone, back-button

I am making a Windows Phone app. If the user is using the app for the first time, it takes the person to the registration page. On successful registration, the user goes to the main page.

Suppose, the user is taken on the registration page and when the user clicks on back button without registration, he is pulled back to registration page because of the code on MainPage.xaml. The code for MainPage.xaml is as follows:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)

    If Not (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("IsFirstLaunchDone")) Then
        NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/Registration.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
    End If

End Sub
```

SO when a user is on Registration page and he taps back button, he again comes to registration page, I want the app to skip coming back to MainPage.xaml if registration is not done and exit the app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your registration page code behind.

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);

        if (UserHasntRegistered)
        {
            try
            {
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            } catch(Exception exception)
            {
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```